# About chemistry mechanism

Tags: chemfig

I have asked so many questions in drawing chemistry mechanism. I would like to draw the catalytic hydration mechanism.

In step 2, the curly arrow is crossing the bond. Can I make the curly arrow to make it like the photo?

In step 3 and 4, the compound are misaligned.

Also, should I stop using Latex? I seems dont know some place how it works or it is only because I am a beginner of Latex? Can any advanced or intermediate users give me some opinion?

```
\schemestart

\chemfig{-[:-60]C(-[:240])=_[@{a1}]C(-[:60])(-[:-60])}

\arrow{0}[,0]\+

\chemfig{@{a2}H-[@{a3}]@{a4}OSO_{3}H}

\arrow{<<->[slow]}

\chemfig{-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90])-@{b1}\chemabove{C}{\oplus}(-[:-90])(-)}

\arrow{0}[,0]\subscheme{\+}

\chemfig{HSO_{4}^{-}}

\arrow(@c5--){<->>[*{0}\chemfig{H_{2}@{b2}\charge{0=\:}{O}}]}[-90]

\chemfig{-C(-[:90]H)(-[:270])-C(-[:270])(-)(-[:90]@{d2}{\charge{180:3pt=$\scriptstyle\oplus$}O}H(-[@{d1}:90]@{d4}H))}

\subscheme{\+}

\chemfig{H_{2}@{d3}\charge{00=\:}{O}}

\arrow[-180,2]

\chemfig{-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90])-C(-[:90]\charge{90=\:}{O}H)(-[:-90])-}

\schemestop

\par

\chemmove{
    \draw(a1)..controls +(100:5mm) and +(145:5mm)..(a2);
    \draw(a3)..controls +(100:5mm) and +(145:5mm)..(a4);
    \draw(b2)..controls +(0:10mm) and +(45:10mm)..(b1);
    \draw(d1)..controls +(180:5mm) and +(145:5mm)..(d2);
    \draw(d3)..controls +(0:10mm) and +(0:5mm)..(d4);
}
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Regarding the curly arrow: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609481/how-can-i-draw-a-mini-wave/609484#609484. Please do not ask multiple questions per post. Also you may consider to accept previous answers.

Comment: Regarding the curved arrow intersecting the bond: You may want to ajust the length and angle values of the `\draw` commands to your needs. `\draw(a1)..controls +(75:35mm) and +(90:5mm)..(a2);` for example should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{C(-[:120])(-[:240])=[@{a1}]C(-[:60])(-[:-60])}
\+
\chemfig{@{a2}H-[@{a3}]@{a4}OSO_{3}H}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<<->[slow]}
\chemfig{C(-[4])(-[2]H)(-[6])-@{b1}\chemabove{C}{\oplus}(-[6])(-[0])}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){0}[,0.06]
\+
\chemfig{HSO_4^{-}}
\arrow(@c2--){<->>[*{0}\chemfig{H_{2}@{b2}\charge{0=\:}{O}}]}[-90]
\chemfig{C(-[4])(-[2]H)(-[6])-C(-[6])(-)(-[2]@{d2}{\charge{180:3pt=$\scriptstyle\oplus$}O}H(-[@{d1}2]@{d4}H))}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){0}[,0.06]
\+
\chemfig{H_{2}@{d3}\charge{0=\:}{O}}
\arrow(@c4.mid west--.mid east)[-180,2]
\chemfig{C(-[4])(-[2]H)(-[6])-C(-[2]\charge{90=\:}{O}H)(-[6])(-[0])}
\schemestop
\chemmove{
    \draw[shorten <=1pt] (a1)..controls +(100:5mm) and +(145:5mm)..(a2);
    \draw(a3)..controls +(100:5mm) and +(145:5mm)..(a4);
    %\draw(b2)..controls +(0:10mm) and +(45:10mm)..(b1);
        \draw[shorten <=5pt, shorten >=2pt]
            (b2) ..controls +(0:15mm) and +(-45:10mm).. (b1);
    \draw(d1)..controls +(180:5mm) and +(145:5mm)..(d2);
    \draw[shorten <=5pt, shorten >=2pt]
        (d3) ..controls +(0:15mm) and +(0:20mm).. (d4);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to ask how does the @c4 counts. I saw in the manual of chemfig there is some example but in page 57 the last sample. I do not understand why there is no c2 in that example.

Comment: @some one  In the example at the end of page 56 of chemfig v1.6b manual, c2 is xx (subscheme) and in the example at the start of the page 57, c2 is tsoin. In my answer, add the line " \setchemfig{scheme debug=true}" before the "\schemestart" to see the c4.